Flutter build fails after updating dependencies
My project worked fine until I've tried to install a new package, and all of the sudden my previously working packages isn't working, here is an error from "google_sign_in" package:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  
What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_sign_in_android:androidJdkImage'. Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/pezhvak/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar. > Error while executing process /Users/pezhvak/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/pezhvak/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/4c4ec335038410e4c484aa095ddf9d65-c534e869-7e4e-4da9-a418-dec3e27819d0/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/pezhvak/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/4c4ec335038410e4c484aa095ddf9d65-c534e869-7e4e-4da9-a418-dec3e27819d0/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}  
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.  
BUILD FAILED in 2s Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I've tried:

clearing gradle cache
installing the new api (Android 15 Api Level 35)
removing and reinstalling packages
downgrading the package version

Neither worked, i even tried to install google_sign_in in a fresh new project and the problem is still there, the same issue is happening with url_launcher package.

Note: this is not happening with IOS, it works fine with it.


So it turned out to be the issue with the new android studio LadyBug.
After macros release 15.0.1 (Sequoia) I've updated everything with it but it didn't show up the issue until i tried to install a new package (i guess because of gradle caches).
How to fix:
Open android/settings.gradle and change this line:
id "com.android.application" version "8.7.0" apply false

Then open android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change this:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

This should fix the issue, however there will be errors in the logs, to fix them do this:
open android/app/build.gradle and make sure ndkVersion is set to 27.0.12077973:
ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973"

There might be better ways to do this, and it will be probably fixed soon by flutter, but until then this will hopefully help you continue developing your app.
Sources:

FAILED TO RUN AFTER UPDATING TO ANDROID STUDIO LADY BUG
How to change Android minSdkVersion in Flutter Project?


Run cmd ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version latest inside android directory for Gradle update
